# how to deploy react as frontend and drf (django rest framework) on same server( Digitalocean or aws )

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, digital-ocean

I have Django react app. I am using drf for apis and react as front-end. i want to deploy them on digital ocean separately on same server. any suggestions?

Comment: Run your DRF cgi server and React server app on different ports or use different sockets. Which HTTP server do you use?

Comment: i'm using nginx but can you be more specific about deployment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I must say that my main stack is Django-uWSGI-NGNIX. There is a great instruction, which you can use with DigitalOcean:

[How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

And this one for Gunicorn:

[How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I recommend trying to deploy your Django App on the server first, using these instructions. Maybe it will be just a simple one-page project.
After that you can modify your ngnix configs. In my case it will be:

```
upstream my_backend_server_name_or_whatever {
# server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; -- if you want to use sockets
server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {

    listen      80;
    server_name     yourdomain.com/api; #or /back, /backend, /what_you_like
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;  

    location /media #your locantions configs
    ....

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  my_backend_server_name_or_whatever;
        include     /path/to/file/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to run your CGI server on port 5000. After that, you can access to your Django app through **yourdomain.com/api** and it will upstream to localhost:5000.
Try this step with your current Django app. After that, you can configure your DRF to work with these links.

If it will work, the next step. Run your NodeJS server on the other port, like 5100. You can find the same instructions for Webpack or raw NodeJS. After that use the same technics, but for the NodeJS server. In my case:

```
upstream my_frontend_server_or_whatever {
    server localhost:5100;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ide.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ide.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_frontend_server_or_whatever;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect    off;
    }
```

}

Now you can save both files as **backend.conf** and **frontend.conf**, run ngnix and check all configs like in instructions above. After that, you can use **yourdomain.com/api** links in your React App.

In my opinion, this is the simplest way to try React+DRF. But these configs only for development!! Not for production.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: what would be the better way for production

Comment: It depends on your project. You can create the correct DRF app, run the Django CGI server on a concrete socket (for security purposes), build React bundle of your React app through webpack and attach it to main "index.html" in your Django app. In this case you do not need to separate apps, you will use only one CGI-server.